# Biblatex unitalisize in text citation

Tags: biblatex, citing, italic-correction

I'm trying to get a Harvard citation style working but I don't know how to unitalisize the title in an in text citation. I'm using pdflatex and biber to produce my results. pdflatex is version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 on Arch Linux, and biber is version 1.9. This is my MWE.

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=1.0in]{geometry}

\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}
\setlength{\parindent}{0.5in}

\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing

\usepackage[
    style=authoryear,
    urldate=comp,
    backend=biber
]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{test.bib}

\title{The Title}
\author{John Smith}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

Hello world \autocite{test}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

And my bib

```
@online{test,
    year = {n.d.},
    urldate = {2014-12-10},
    title = {My title},
    url = {http://www.google.com},
    note = {[online]}
}
```

[image: example image]

As you can see, the title is in italics in the in text citation, I was wondering how I could make it so that it's not italics, but still keep it italisized in my references.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the original `\DeclareFieldFormat{citetitle}{\mkbibemph{#1}}`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=1.0in]{geometry}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mytest.bib}
@online{test,
    year = {n.d.},
    urldate = {2014-12-10},
    title = {My title},
    url = {http://www.google.com},
    note = {[online]}
}
\end{filecontents}

\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}
\setlength{\parindent}{0.5in}

\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing

\usepackage[
    style=authoryear,
    urldate=comp,
    backend=biber
]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{mytest.bib}

\title{The Title}
\author{John Smith}
\date{\today}


\DeclareFieldFormat{citetitle}{{#1}}


\begin{document}
\maketitle

Hello world \autocite{test}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]